# How to show empty data message in Datatables

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Suppose i get empty data from server sometimes, i want to display No Data found message in DataTables?. How is this possible?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

If you want to customize the message that being shown on empty table use this:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "oLanguage": {
        "sEmptyTable":     "My Custom Message On Empty Table"
    }
} );
```

Since Datatable 1.10 you can do the following:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "language": {
        "emptyTable":     "My Custom Message On Empty Table"
    }
} );
```

---

For the **complete availble datatables custom messages** for the table take a look at the following link [reference/option/language](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, hey can you pls help me on this question i.e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376692/loading-script-from-js-file. i hope u will have idea. its related to datatable

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, how can we show custom message in cell for empty record attributes.

Comment: @codemilan, you should google for Column rendering , see this https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html , look at the js code that renders the first column, in your case you can add a check for empty column and render whatever you want for that cell

Comment: @Daniel pls check this . Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431205/why-does-datatable-doesnt-show-empty-data-message

Comment: datatable will throw alert before user sees this, any workaround?

Answer (score 18):

Later versions of `dataTables` have the following `language` settings (taken from [here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/language.html)):

- `"infoEmpty"` - displayed when there are no records in the table
- `"zeroRecords"` - displayed when there no records matching the filtering

e.g.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "language": {
        "infoEmpty": "No records available - Got it?",
    }
});
```

Note: As the property names do not contain any special characters you can remove the quotes:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    language: {
        infoEmpty: "No records available - Got it?",
    }
});
```

Comment: `infoEmpty` is actually for the info part of table. see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeffxiao/hnj8yusm/1/)

Answer (score 4):

Late to the game, but you can also use a [localisation file](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/)

DataTable provides a `.json` localized file, which contains the key `sEmptyTable` and the corresponding localized message.

For example, just download the localized json file on the above [link](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/#Translations), then initialize your `Datatable` like that :

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "language": {
        "url": "path/to/your/json/file.json"
    }
});
```

IMHO, that's a lot cleaner, because your localized content is located in an external file.

This syntax works for *DataTables 1.10.16*, I didn't test on previous versions.

Answer (score 2):

I was finding same but lastly i found an answer. I hope this answer help you so much.

when your array is empty then you can send empty array just like

```
if(!empty($result))
        {
            echo json_encode($result);
        }
        else
        {
            echo json_encode(array('data'=>''));
        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that if you are returning server side data - you must supply the Data attribute even if there isn't any. It doesn't read the `recordsTotal` or `recordsFiltered` but relies on the count of the data object

Comment: my data set return data =null recordsTotal = 0 recordsFiltered =0 but that time dataTable doesnt show any message. its stuck on processing . how can i show default 'no result found ; message when data=null. pls advice

Comment: You can set processing:false I believe as a parameter and your data returned must have a 'Data' key in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

This is a just a nice idea. that, you can Add class in body, and hide/show table while there is **no data in table**. This works perfect for me. You can design custom **NO Record Found error message** when there is no record in table, you can add class "no-record", and when there is 1 or more than one record, you can remove class and show datatable

Here is jQuery code.

```
$('#default_table').DataTable({

    // your stuff here

    "fnFooterCallback": function (nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {
        if (aiDisplay.length > 0) {
            $('body').removeClass('no-record');
        }
        else {
            $('body').addClass('no-record');
        }
    }
});
```

Here is CSS

```
.no-record #default_table{display:none;}
```

and [here is Official link](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/35602/how-to-add-a-class-in-if-no-record-found).

Answer (score -1):

By default the grid view will take care, just pass empty data set.