# How to change a default message in DataTable,When 0 records found to be display in DataTable

Tags: datatable

How to change a default message in DataTable, When 0 records found to be display in DataTable. Currently it shows "Loading..." continuously.I want to set message for this case "No records found".Please guide me,Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid Rendering "No Data Available in the table" in Datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522399/avoid-rendering-no-data-available-in-the-table-in-datatables)

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code into `.dataTable();` .

- [Empty Table](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/28351/datatable-loading-message)

---

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
   "language": {
     "emptyTable": "No data available in table"
   }
});
```

- [Loading message](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/28351/datatable-loading-message)

---

```
"language": {
   "loadingRecords": "Please wait - loading..."
}
```