# Why does dataTable doesnt show empty data message?

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10

This is how i return my dataset when no results found for particular search in dataTable serverside processing

```
data :null
recordsFiltered:"0"
recordsTotal:"0"
```

but frondend doesnt show any no result found message .its stuck with processing. and console give an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

maybe this is null means my data=null.

how can I show datatable default message saying no search results. ? i'm using datatable version 1.10.13 with serverside processing , pls advice

Answer (score 3):

You need to return empty array in `data` property, see sample JSON response below:

```
{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsFiltered": 0,
    "recordsTotal": 0,
    "data": []
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much.. I was sending `$return['data'][] = []` instead of `return['data'] = []` Now it's working! Thanks a lot again!